# Showing image in cell causes textbox to move down

Tags: html, css

I have a cell in a table where I show a textbox. In the same cell to the right of this textbox I have an image that I hide to start with. The textbox is centered in the cell, but when I show the image (which happens when the value in the textbox changes) the textbox moves down so it's bottom is lined up with the image. How can I make it so this doesn't happen and the texbox stays where it was.

I get I'm using inline, I'll change it once I get it sorted. I just dislike moving back and forth or having 2 windows open when trying to get 1 element worked out.

```
<td valign="middle">
    <input type="text" style="width: 100px;" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="reset_onClick(@id)"><img src="~/Content/images/reset-icon.png" style="display: none; width: 32px; height: 25px; margin: 0px;" /></a>
</td>
```

In javascript when the text changes in the textbox:

```
imgReset.css("display", "inline");
```

Comment: Please provide a working example to see the effect. [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) can be a good option to save your example.

Comment: Sounds like a `vertical-align:baseline` issue. Oh and `valign` has been deprecated,

Comment: @Paulie_D I put that in both the input and img tags and made it middle. It for sure helps. Now the textbox moves up ever so slightly. It is better then before but would love to not have it move at all.

Comment: You could use any other value in `vertical-align` ...try them all out see which works best for you. Perhaps "top"?